# How to find the mincut of this flow network?

Tags: graphs

[image: Picture of network]

I am trying to find the minimum cut of this flow network, but I feel like I have the cut wrong. Based off this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33834/how-to-find-a-minimum-cut-of-a-network-flow), I should try to find all reachable vertices in the residual network once there are no augmenting paths, and set that to partition "A", but then I get this weird cut. Is this the right cut?

Comment: Yes this is the right. Just compare the max flow with cut capacity. They must be the same by min-cut max flow theorem. Here cut capacity = max flow = 5.

Comment: Also, note an important property of a min cut that any edge that goes from $B$ to $A$ must have a 0 flow in the original graph. Here $B = V \setminus A$